# Error: unknown api groups settings.k8s.io from kube-apiserver

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am using
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:25:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

I tried to allow PodPreset by adding *--runtime-config=settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1=true* to *kube-apiserver.yaml*

After added this line, the kube-apiserver produced errors

This is the logs by `kubectl logs kube-apiserver-master-0 -n kube-system`

Flag --insecure-port has been deprecated, This flag has no effect now and will be removed in v1.24.
I0203 01:12:59.519598       1 server.go:632] external host was not specified, using 10.1.0.5
**Error: unknown api groups settings.k8s.io**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is removed in v1.20. Please refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#deprecation